# Why Macports does not show the apple xcode compiler through "port select gcc"?

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, macports

Recently I updated my Mac's XCode and Command Line tools to version 6.4 (I'm running on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5). After I did that change, to install a new package with MacPorts, I was forced to run a "port selfupdate". However, after I did that, something broke in my system. Particularly, the usual `port select gcc` does not display the apple compilers installed with XCode. It only displays:

```
Available versions for gcc:
mp-gcc48
none (active)
```

I have to say that, trying to solve a compilation problem (that's how I found out the issue), I uninstalled one or two mp-gcc versions. However, I remember that the apple versions should have been listed there.

To make sure the apple compilers are installed: running the command **xcode-select --install** displays the following:

`xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

and **xcode-select -p** displays the following:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

So, the compilers are there. My `~/.profile` file contains the following line:

```
MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-05-13_at_00:53:37: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PAT
```

But, indeed, that's the usual change made my MacPorts.

Does anyone knows what is happening? I need to work with the apple compiler without destroying the MacPorts environment.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: thanks for the nice answers, so indeed `none` is the system's (xcode) installation for macport. For the record, I tried to select the macports gcc and then none, to see if there was a broken link and indeed this happened:

```
sudo port select gcc mp-gcc48
Selecting 'mp-gcc48' for 'gcc' failed: symlink: /opt/local/etc/select/gcc/current -> mp-gcc48: file already exists
```

After I manually deleted `/opt/local/etc/select/gcc/current`, the `port select gcc` command worked well and setting `sudo port select gcc none` worked well after that.

Comment: Is this the compiler you want to use for your projects or for compiling Macports *ports* themselves?

Comment: It is for usage with my projects. I want to leave the Macports environment as is.

Comment: I would recommend simply using `CC=clang` in your `Makefile`s (or whatever), or explicitly using `/usr/bin/clang`.

Answer (score 1):

The port select gives you the option to select a MacPorts compiler for the command `gcc`, or to `sudo port select gcc none`, which then uses the system compiler.

I.e., the option you are looking for is now called "none". This makes sense, since MacPorts cannot know what the system compiler is, or even if one is installed. It may be clang or gcc depending on the version of XCode. Note that on newer versions of XCode/OSX, there is no gcc, only clang, and `gcc`/`g++` are links to `clang`/`clang++`.

EDIT:
This is now the same for all available "port groups". For example on my system the following configuration is active:

```
port select --summary

Name       Selected     Options
====       ========     =======
clang      none         mp-clang-3.7 none
cython     cython34     cython27 cython34 none
db         none         db46 db48 none
gcc        none         mp-gcc47 mp-gcc49 mp-gcc5 none
ipython    ipython34    ipython27 ipython34 none
llvm       none         mp-llvm-3.5 mp-llvm-3.7 none
mysql      none         mysql56 none
nosetests  none         nosetests27 nosetests34 none
pip        pip34        pip34 none
python     python34     python26-apple python27 python27-apple python34 none
python2    python27     python26-apple python27 python27-apple none
python3    none         python34 none
sphinx     py34-sphinx  py27-sphinx py34-sphinx none
wxWidgets  none         wxWidgets-3.0 none
```

For instance, if I want to switch back to the system default python, I say

```
sudo port select python none
```

and for python3 (for which there is no system default), I say

```
sudo port select python3 none
```

Comment: This is different to how Macports does it with python, where the apple version is selectable explicitly.  Installing `clang` via Macports doesn't give the option to select `apple-clang` either.

Comment: I just clarified my answer. Indeed, this is now the way it is done for all port groups, i.e., also python, clang, etc. You always `port select <portgroup> none` to select the system default. For python, it seems python27-apple is left for some reason. Don't know why.

Comment: I see `python26-apple` and `python27-apple` in your list (same for me), which is confusing...

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right. To be precise, there are `python26-apple`, `python27-apple` *and* `none`. So `none` falls back to the system default, which is `/usr/bin/python`, while `python26-apple` selects `/usr/bin/python2.6` and `python27-apple` selects `/usr/bin/python2.7` (both of which are symlinks to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/...`

Comment: Agreed.  That makes sense; Macports can handle multiple versions of a program provided by Apple.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info on this. There was something strange in addition, as I tried to change to `mp-gcc48` and then to `none`, to see if it made a difference, or if it fixes a broken link. It seems indeed selecting another gcc version did not work. It complained that `/opt/local/etc/select/gcc/current` already exists. Removing it fixed the problem.